# How to get average of same word more than X time per group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I get the average of **same** word more than 4 times per group ?

In other words:

I want to calculate for each group (`name`) the number of sentences which contains same word at least 4 times vs the total number of sentences of the group ?

Example:

```
id | name | sentences
---------------------
1  |  aa  | david david david david
2  |  aa  | david david is at home
3  |  bb  | I'm king
4  |  cc  | where r u going
4  |  dd  | lol lol lol lol
```

results:

```
name | avg
----------
aa   |  0.5   (1 sentence contain the words 'david' 4 times). total instances of 'aa' group is 2
bb   |  0.0   (0 sentence contains same word 4 times) 
cc   |  0.0   (0 sentence contains same word 4 times)
dd   |  1.0   (1 sentence contains same word 'lol' 4 times). total instances of 'dd' group is 1
```

I'm using `python 3.6.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First count words if same values `>=` per `sentences` by `Counter` and then aggregate `mean`:

```
from collections import Counter

df['avg'] = df['sentences'].apply(lambda x: sum(v>=4 for k,v in Counter(x.split()).items()))

df = df.groupby('name', as_index=False)['avg'].mean()
print (df)
  name  avg
0   aa  0.5
1   bb  0.0
2   cc  0.0
3   dd  1.0
```