# How to get average of continuously same word more than X time per group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My question is similar to that question:

[How to get average of same word more than X time per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63503199/how-to-get-average-of-same-word-more-than-x-time-per-group/63503335#63503335)

but here, I want to get the average of same word **continuously** per group (group = `name`) more than 4 times.

Example:

```
id | name | sentences
---------------------
1  |  aa  | david hi david david david
2  |  aa  | david david is at home
3  |  bb  | I'm king
4  |  cc  | where r u going
5  |  dd  | lol lol lol lol lol lol
6  |  ee  | abc abc cc abc abc abc abc cc
7  |  ee  | dd dd dd ee dd dd dd
```

I want to get the following results:

```
name | avg
----------
aa   |  0.0   (0 sentence contain the words 'david' continuously 4 times in ). total instances of 'aa' group is 2
bb   |  0.0   (0 sentence contains same word continuously 4 times) 
cc   |  0.0   (0 sentence contains same word continuously 4 times)
dd   |  1.0   (1 sentence contains same word 'lol' continuously 4 times). total instances of 'dd' group is 1
ee   |  0.5   (1 sentence contains same word 'abc' continuously 4 times). total instances of 'dd' group is 2


I'm using python 3.6.8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count continuous occurrences of words `4` or more times in a row using [`Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) then using [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) group the series `cnt` on `name` and aggregate using `mean` to get grouped average.

```
cnt = df['sentences'].str.count(r'(\w+)(\s\1){3,}')
avg = cnt.groupby(df['name']).mean().reset_index(name='avg')
```

**Details:**

```
print(cnt)
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    0
Name: sentences, dtype: int64

print(avg)
  name  avg
0   aa  0.0
1   bb  0.0
2   cc  0.0
3   dd  1.0
4   ee  0.5
```